# Cassandra Data Model - Column Families into CQL Table

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

Assume that I have a sample User table with fields (userid, username, dob, loc, email). I have different columns names like one user can have only userid, user name and second user can have userid, username, dob and third users may have other columns and so on (representing wide column store). Each user can have their own set of columns. How to represent this in a single CQL table as data is sparse across different columns. Do I need to go with multiple user tables to represent this info?

Please suggest how to convert sample table into CQL table.

Comment: Cassandra requires a query-based modeling approach.  As you haven't said anything about the queries you are required to support, it is impossible to make educated decisions about how your table(s) should look.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I am assuming that data needs to be stored in column families with appropriate Row Key and Column Key and Column Values. But once it is done, how do we decide to display info in CQL tables.

Comment: For example, assume I have same data like this:                                            User(userid, uname, email,dob,loc,mobile,landlinenum)  As cassandra supports schemaless(dynamic columns can be added), it may happen that one user may have few columns and other user may have few other colums (there ca be rows which takes same number of columns and other rows may take other columns as well. How do I convert this into a CQL table as i have all different columns for different row keys.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're asking.  No, you should be able to build all columns into a single table.  Let's say that I create a `users` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  userid bigint,
  username text, 
  email text,
  dob text,
  loc text,
  mobile text,
  landlinenum text,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid));
```

And then I INSERT some rows like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (userid,username,email,loc,mobile) VALUES (0,'mreynolds','mal@serenity.com','Minneapolis','111-555-1234');
INSERT INTO users (userid,username,email,loc,landlinenum,dob) VALUES (1,'jcobb','jayne@serenity.com','Minneapolis','111-555-3464','19620227');
INSERT INTO users (userid,username,email,loc,mobile) VALUES (2,'dbook','derrial@serenity.com','New York','111-555-2349');
INSERT INTO users (userid,username,email,loc,mobile,dob) VALUES (3,'stam','simon@serenity.com','San Francisco','111-555-8899','19750416');
INSERT INTO users (userid,username,email,loc,dob) VALUES (4,'rtam','river@serenity.com','San Francisco','19810724');
```

If I run an unbound query to pull back all rows and columns, I see this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM users;

 userid | dob      | email                | landlinenum  | loc           | mobile       | username
--------+----------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------
      2 |     null | derrial@serenity.com |         null |      New York | 111-555-2349 |     dbook
      3 | 19750416 |   simon@serenity.com |         null | San Francisco | 111-555-8899 |      stam
      4 | 19810724 |   river@serenity.com |         null | San Francisco |         null |      rtam
      0 |     null |     mal@serenity.com |         null |   Minneapolis | 111-555-1234 | mreynolds
      1 | 19620227 |   jayne@serenity.com | 111-555-3464 |   Minneapolis |         null |     jcobb

(5 rows)
```

So this should tell you a couple of things.

1. Cassandra isn't really "schema-less" in the same sense that it was in the pre-CQL world.  You do have to define each column in your table definition.
2. With #1 being said, you *do not* have to provide a value for each column.
3. Columns which have *not* been assigned a value display as "null."  Keep-in-mind, that they are not true null values, they just display that way.
4. In my INSERTs, I only specified the columns for which I had corresponding values.  I did not set the others to empty or null.  Explicitly setting a column value to null creates a tombstone.

Now to my point about understanding your query requirements, you usually want to create a table for each query required.  I have the "users" table keyed by `userid`...but really, how useful is that?  Applications typically query by things like `email` or `loc`.

To handle email, I would create a new table with the same column definitions called "users_by_email."  The main difference (other than the name) would be the PRIMARY KEY definition: `PRIMARY KEY (email,username)`

Then I could query a user by email like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM users_by_email WHERE email='river@serenity.com';

 email              | username | dob      | landlinenum | loc           | mobile | userid
--------------------+----------+----------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------
 river@serenity.com |     rtam | 19810724 |        null | San Francisco |   null |      4

(1 rows)
```

That's why knowing your query patterns makes a difference.  In the first example, the "users" table cannot support a query by `email`.

Comment: Thank you Aaron for the detailed explanation. Appreciate for your efforts for answering my queries. Thank you so much once again.